# Azure Web App Deployment shows hostingstart.html

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy a MVC .Net Core 2.2 project to Azure, but all I get is a blue screen with the message "Your App Service app is up and running".  I think this is the hostingstart.html file created during deployment.

The project I am deploying is exactly what Visual Studio 15.9.5 creates, no code changes.  I can run the project locally, but cannot deploy.

If I change the URL by adding "home/index" on the end, I get the blue screen again.  I created an html page and saved it in wwwroot, deployed this, and cannot view that page.

++++++ UPDATE ++++++

Thanks for the replies, below is more detail about how I create and publish the project:

In Visual Studio, I Click "Add New Project", select ASP.NET Core Web Application, choose Core 2.2 with no authentication and HTTPS support.  I run the project by clicking F5.  To publish, I create a new profile, leave the default values, no app insights.  The website is published.

The home page is a blue screen, and I cannot access the home/index page.

[image: blue screen]
<sub>(source: [windows.net](https://declensionstorage.blob.core.windows.net/read-only/blue-screen.png))</sub>

Comment: what do you mean you cannot deploy? how are you deploying? look at this another question I am answering which seems similar to your request.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54122165/how-to-deploy-a-web-app-to-azure-cloud-service-from-a-mac/54122874#54122874

Comment: Please share more information, what about your app settings and how did you deploy. Maybe you could refer to this doc to deploy .net core web.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-dotnet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a NuGet package that the New Project wizard was omitting:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc
```

I added this to the project, rebuilt, and the deployment worked as expected.